# openjdk 1.8 package for centos 6.5

Tags: centos6, java

I want to move our production setup to openjdk 1.8 soon. Currently we're running openjdk 1.7u55 on centos 6.5.

The trouble is that I can't seem to get a straight answer out of google on where to find a yum repository with 1.8. Has a usable rpm been released somewhere? If so, where? If not, is there a rough ETA when this might happen (e.g. centos 7 or epel?). I could probably wait a few weeks but not much longer.

I was able to find some fedora packages at least: https://apps.fedoraproject.org/packages/java-1.8.0-openjdk/builds

So, this suggest people are working on this at least but I have no idea if these packages are stable with centos (or work at all).

For clarity, I know it is early days with jdk 1.8 and am well aware of the tradeoffs. I'm not looking for build instructions or instruction on how to download Oracle Java from Oracle, which with their lack of a yum repo and license click through is annoying.

Comment: I just down load and unpack the Linux version from Oracle.  There is no click through.

Comment: I ended up downloading their rpm (and clicked through the license agreement, can't seem to avoid that) and put that in our repository. It seems to be the only reasonably supported way to run java 8 on centos. The point is, there is still no openjdk 8 build for centos.

Comment: +1 and there should be.

Comment: This question is becoming the "straight answer out of Google" for how to get OpenJDK 8 with yum.  @JillesvanGurp I suggest you turn your "Update" into an actual answer so it's more obvious.

Comment: I had no idea, so converted it into an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems Epel now has openjdk 1.8.0_25. So this is no longer an issue. Install sudo yum install java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel if you need the jdk instead of the jre.

Comment: I'm trying that within a CentOS Docker image and getting:

    Step 7 : RUN yum -y install java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel && yum clean all
 ---> Running in ef4593276ccd
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Determining fastest mirrors
 * base: mirrors.unifiedlayer.com
 * extras: mirror.oss.ou.edu
 * updates: mirrors.sonic.net
No package java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel available.
Error: Nothing to do
2014/11/26 12:41:42 The command [/bin/sh -c yum -y install java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel && yum clean all] returned a non-zero code: 1


Any idea ?

Comment: http://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel(x86-64) it seems it is available for centos 6.6 but not 7. Go figure.

Comment: You may want to try Zulu openjdk build in docker: https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/azul/zulu-openjdk-centos/